# Reading from csv file and separating into variables in C

Tags: c, file, csv, variables, input

I've been looking for answer here, but didn't find solution for this particular problem.

I have this csv file

[image]

For imagination, I should have creating hockey players from this .csv file as

```
enum POZICE { UTOCNIK = 'U', OBRANCE = 'O', BRANKAR = 'B' };

typedef struct hrac {

int cislo;
char jmeno[50];
enum POZICE pozice;
int utocnaSila;
int obrannaSila;
struct hrac *dalsi;
} tHrac;
```

Number, name, position of player(keeper, defender, etc.), his attack power, defensive power and link to next player.

Creating method:

```
tHrac* vytvorHrace(int cislo, char* jmeno, enum Pozice pozice, int utocnaSila, int obrannaSila) {

tHrac* hrac = (tHrac*)malloc(sizeof(tHrac));
hrac->cislo = cislo;
strcpy(hrac->jmeno, jmeno);
hrac->pozice = pozice;
hrac->utocnaSila = utocnaSila;
hrac->obrannaSila = obrannaSila;
hrac->dalsi = NULL;

}
```

And now the core of my problem, loading method

```
void nactiSeznamHracu() {
char *tmp1[30];
char *tmp2[30];
char *tmp3[30];
char *tmp4[30];
char *ch[255];

int a = 0;

FILE* soubor = fopen(SEZNAM, "r");

fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), soubor);
fputs(ch, stdout);

sscanf(ch, "% [^;]%[^;]", tmp1, tmp2); // parsing whole char *ch into smaller pieces, wont work
puts(tmp1,tmp2);

fscanf(soubor, "%c [^;]%s [^;]", tmp3,tmp4); // without saving first line into ch, and cutting it right away
puts(tmp3);

//token = strtok(ch, "\n");
//puts(token);

}
```

I can succesfully load first line, but when I try somehow cut the lines into smaller pieces, like Number,Name,Attack,Deffence,Position, it won't work(or cutting only header into smaller pieces), I tried many ways, more than I've here, but result was always the same... (first two lines of img is unrelated, was just testing tHrac, creating and writing)
[image]

My intention is to create for cycle where it will load first line, load it seperately into variable which i will use to create tHrac and then it skip into next line and same thing ...

But my experience with C is low, so that's why I'm turning on you. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

```
sscanf(ch, "% [^;]%[^;]", tmp1, tmp2); // parsing whole char *ch into 
puts(tmp1,tmp2);
fscanf(soubor, "%c [^;]%s [^;]", tmp3,tmp4);
```

`tmp1` ,`tmp2` and all are array `30` of pointers to `char` , and passing wrong arguments would cause undefined behavior.

In case either you need to *use individual pointer of these arrays after allocating memory to them* ,

Or use them as array to `char` or `char *` , and you need to allocate memory in latter case and then pass them to `sscanf` or `fscanf`.

**Note**- Also you should check `return` value of `sscanf` and `fscanf` functions .